# Spark Dataframes , WithColumn

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I tried the below code in Spark-shell and it works fine.

```
val df2 = df3.withColumn("Escore", when($"col2" === $"col3",10).otherwise(0))orderBy(asc("col2"),desc("Escore"),desc("col5"))
```

But when i try the same command in IntelliJ's Scala with SBT, I am facing the below error.

in Scala IDE :

```
val df2: DataFrame = df3.withColumn("Escore": String,when($"col2" === $"col3",10).otherwise(0))orderBy(asc("col2"),desc("Escore"),desc("col5"))
```

> ERROR : Not able to resolve symbol "WHEN" .

Could anyone please provide a sample code or syntax of how to code a withColumn of dataframe in IntelliJ Scala.

My SBT is :

```
name := "SparkSqlExample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tried on spark-shell this works fine but even on `intelliJ` it is working fine. i think you forget to import the sql functions.

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

try this. this will resolve the issue if not add the comment
Thanks